# C#: stack with two type item

Tags: c#

i want make stack with two different type

so i try to write this but give error:

```
Stack<[string,int]> S = new Stack<[string,int]>();
S.Push(["aaa",0]);
```

i tried this way before:

```
public class SItem{
    public string x;
    public int y;

    public SItem(string text,int index){
        this.x = text;
        this.y = index;
    }
}
Stack<SItem> S = new Stack<SItem>();
SItem Start = new SItem("aaa",0);
S.Push(Start);
```

but i want it be very simple to use like what i write before

any idea?

Comment: What you wrote before isn't allowed, so use what is working for you, also the second *(working)* code looks more readable.

Comment: No (comment, as "no" really not considered as an answer). Functional languages may give you syntax close to what you like - try F# or Haskell.

Comment: this is part of parsing algorithm and is homework that must be writing by C#, is there any way to create custom type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var stack = new Stack<Tuple<string, int>>();
stack.Push(Tuple.Create("string", 0));
var item = stack.Pop();
```

It removes the need to write a custom class, but on the downside, as **@AlexeiLevenkov** commented, makes code less readable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yep, agreed. But it does not mean that it should never be used. Just something to consider, not necessarily to select.

Comment: `Tuple<string,int> item = stack.Pop();`

Comment: They are handy if you dont want to create a whole class just to support one procedure, especially if that procedure is in a chain of functions against a collection.

Comment: @AlphaElf You can simplify that to `var item = stack.Pop();` although it's a matter of debate whether that's a good thing to do or not.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yep, I updated the post. (It is indeed questionable if `var` or explicit type should be used. But I had the `var` in the first line already, so I re-used it.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a KeyValuePair or Tuple (depending on your version of .Net)

```
Stack<KeyValuePair<string, int>> stack = new Stack<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
stack.Push(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("string", 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use a [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Stack<KeyValuePair<string, int>> stack;
```